# MVC refreshing page after Ajax call to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following in my controller:

```
public async Task < ViewResult > Favourites(string ids) {
    // code that fetches book data from API 

    if (data != null)

    {
        var bookList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Book[] > (data);

        foreach(var book in bookList) {
            var matches = new List < bookList > ();
            if (bookList.All(book => ids.Contains(book.Id))) {
                matches.Add(book);
            }

            return View("Index", matches.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

And this in my view:

```
   <script>

        function getFavouriteBooks() {
            var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Home/Favourites',
                data: { ids: localStorage.getItem('bookIds') },
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.href = '/Home/Favourites/' + ids ;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

I don't think `window.location.href = '/Home/Favourites/' + ids;` is correct but my goal is to reload the page with the View called from my controller (`return View("Index", matches.ToArray());`) and am not sure how to do this.

The first time the controller is hit the parameter is correctly populated with the data, but the second time it's empty. I know this is because it's empty.

Please can someone explain how to get the View to load after the ajax call with the `ids` parameter?

Comment: Did you see my update? I tested it in visual studio and it was working properly. You should let me know, If it still not working for you.

Comment: @Sergey thank you but that was for a different question of passing the values back to the controller, this is for refreshing the View after.

Comment: You could ask me how to do this. Now I posted an incorrect  code again and expecting that somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: When we use AJAX, we typically do not want to navigate away from the current page (no full page reloads). Instead, we might 1) return a partial html fragment to swap with a current html element (like a li list) 2) return a status response (maybe to give a pop-up alert). By using `window.location` you have the browser navigate to the new location -- if this is the case, you would just do a standard form submission and skip the AJAX.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to change the ajax call success part to:

```
      success: function (data) {
                        $("body").html(data);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller only called by a get request
if you want to get a result from your controller change ajax setting or add HttpPost attribute to your controller.

```
type: "GET",
```